# Rearranging text(string) using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is a simple question, but I'm just learning javascript.
I have text "Smith, John - PPP". How can I rearrange this to just "John Smith"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you'll match a pattern in your original string, extract pieces of interest and rearrange them. A common tool to use are [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

In your example:

```
var s = "Smith, John - PPP";
var r = s.replace(/^([^,]+), ?([^ ]+).*$/, "$2 $1");
```

`r` will hold the substituted string.

Caveat:

Regular expressions are a helpful tool. They are no panacea. Carefully check whether the tool you are about to use is suitable for the task at hand (a screwdriver is a helpful too as well, unless you try to use it to hammer a nail into the wall) !

In particular, pattern-matching against lexical representations of semi-structured data (read: html, xml) is usually ill-advised without employing more powerful tools. If you have doubts, have a look at the accepted answer to [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Thta was fast! Thanks for replaying so quickly. it partially works, the only issue is that I want to remove the "- PPP". I added another replace(), var r = s.replace(/^([^,]+), ?([^ ]+)/, "$2 $1").replace("- PPP", ""), and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to do the replace. Just add a `.*` to the regular expression at the end: `s.replace(/^([^,]+), ?([^ ]+).*/, "$2 $1");`

Answer (score 2):

Splitting and joining strings can be easy using libraries as JQuery (http://jquery.com/) but javascript allows it from base this way;

`Smith, John - PPP'.split(', ')[1]`

After splitting you can play with your string parts as any array:

```
var name = 'Smith, John - PPP';
alert(name.split(' ')[1]+' '+name.split(' ')[0].split(',')[0]); //Will alert "John Smith"
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick solution using split, if the string has a constant format:

```
var data = 'Smith, John - PPP';
data = data.split(' - ')[0].split(', ');

var result = data[1] + ' ' + data[0];
console.log(result);
```

This is expanding on @ToKeN's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/substring) method

```
var str = "Smith, John - PPP";

var res = str.split(",");

console.log(res[1].substr(1,4) + res[0]); // John Smith
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkbcj/1/)

Note that this example works only with current task as OP has no delimiter or anything else but a simple string

Comment: Your answer only works is the first name is 4 characters long.

Comment: Use a different name: `var str = "Smith, Johnista - PPP";` and you'll see.

Comment: @ToKeN: Try changing the first name to "Johnny" or something else longer than 4 letters, and your code will fail. That's the problem.

Comment: @AndersG Yes, I know, I wrote it specifically with current example

Comment: That's is precisely the thing: it is an example for a set format. Don't assume that is all the data he has to process. ;)

Comment: @SparoHawk Yea, OP's mentioned that just studying `JavaScript`, so I gave another approach to accomplish splitting string